# Async Storage retrieve value of key in item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new to Javascript and react native, and the question itself will be probably very easy to answer.

I'm setting up a AsyncStorage and creating a Item inside the storage, which is a .JSON that has 3 key values to it.

```
const saveDataToStorage = (token, userId, expirationDate) => { 
  AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({
    token: token, 
    userId: userId,
    expiryDate: expirationDate.toISOString()
  }))
};
```

What I want to do now is to retrieve the "userId" value from this item in an other part of the project but here is the problem.

```
var PersonalId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
console.log(PersonalId);
console.log(typeof PersonalId);
```

I know how to access the item itself, but I have no clue how to access the special key inside it. I can not use the command:

```
var PersonalId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').userId;
```

because the item from the AsyncStorage is a **string**, I know this because I got this info from the second line of my code.

```
console.log(typeof PersonalId);
```

How can I access the special key "userId" inside my item "userData" and not the whole item itself? I cant work with the item anyways because its a string, I can not treat it as an object and thats my problem.

Thank you for reading and helping out!

Comment: You are forgetting that you stringified the JSON before saving it to storage.. so you are getting string when you read it. Simply `JSON.parse` the returned string and you should be on your way.

Comment: @rahulpsd18 Your answer was the key to my solution. If you post this comment as an answer I will give you the green hook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting that you stringified the JSON before saving it to storage.. so you are getting string when you read it. Simply `JSON.parse` the returned string and you should be on your way.

```js
const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
const personalId = JSON.parse(userData).userId;
```

You should also wrap the above code in a try-catch to make sure you catch errors when invalid data is tried to be parsed and it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first parse value you are getting from the AsyncStorage into a JSON object using `JSON.parse()`. Try this implementation.

```
const get_data = async () => {
  const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
  const userObject = userData !== null ? JSON.parse(userData) : {};
  const personalId = userObject.userId;
  console.log(personalId);
};
```

Comment: Would not be a problem, the thing is just that in other parts of my code I need the whole dataset as it is, as a string. Only in this special case I need to "convert" it into an object, but your answer helped me anyways because I got to understand JSON.parse() and with that I was able to turn the string into a object and read out properly the key value!